# ExecuteNonQuery : la propiedad connection no se ha inicializado

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Estoy empezando aprender en crear una base de datos en Visual con Access, y me sale este error y no se cual es el problema, porfavor ayudenme en corregirlo y talvez podrian explicarme del problema u de otros.

```
Imports System.Data

Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

Dim cadena As New OleDbConnection

Dim comando As New OleDbCommand

Dim lineaSQL As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try

        cadena.ConnectionString = "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\\Documentos\base de datos\datos.accdb"

        cadena.Open()

        lineaSQL = "INSERT INTO datos(ID,Nombre,Apellido,Edad,Sexo,Direccion,Telefono,Correo)" & "Values(textbox1,textbox2,textbox3,textbox4,textbox5,textbox6,textbox7,textbox8)"


        Dim comando As New OleDb.OleDbCommand


        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBox1.Text)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", TextBox2.Text)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apellido", TextBox3.Text)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Edad", TextBox4.Text)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sexo", TextBox5.Text)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Direccion", TextBox6.Text)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono", TextBox7.Text)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Correo", TextBox8.Text)
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cadena.Close()
        MsgBox("Se agregó el alumno correctamento ", vbInformation, "AGREDADO CORRECTAMENTE")

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(Err.Description)

    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

En este caso, estas haciendo todo bien, salvo por un detalle..

Al crear tu comando, no le estas diciendo que conexion a base de datos a usar.

La misma la creaste (y abriste) aca:

```
cadena.ConnectionString = "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\\Documentos\base de datos\datos.accdb"
cadena.Open()
```

Pero en ningun lugar le dijiste al `comando` cual era la conexion donde trabajar.

Lo unico que tenes que agregar es:

```
comando.Connection = cadena
```

Tene en cuenta de leer sobre el uso de la clausula `using` para evitar tener que hacer un `dispose` de las clases.